# data from firebase realtime database is loading slowly in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to fetch data from firbase and show it in recyclerview. It takes about 30-50 seconds for recyclerview to load the data. There is only one node and still the data takes too much time. Below is the code of my adapter class.

```
public class SellerProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SellerProductsAdapter.ProductsViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<HomeFragmentModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    String productNameO;

    public SellerProductsAdapter(ArrayList<HomeFragmentModel> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_products_single_row, parent, false);
        return new ProductsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getImage1()))
                .into(holder.productImage);
        holder.productName.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getName()));
        holder.productPrice.setText(String.valueOf("Rs. " + data.get(position).getPrice()));
        Log.d("TAG", "Data Product Name is: " + data.get(position).getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
```

Viewholder class:

```
public class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    ShapeableImageView productImage;
    TextView productName, productPrice;
    ConstraintLayout dots;

    public ProductsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeProductImage);
        productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeProductName);
        productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeProductPrice);
        dots = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

        dots.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

I have tried to log the fetched the exact data in my fragment and it takes only 1-2 seconds. below is the HomeFragment code

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null){
    UID = user.getUid();
}

data = new ArrayList<>();

databaseReference.child("Product").child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                HomeFragmentModel homeFragmentModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(HomeFragmentModel.class);
                data.add(homeFragmentModel);
                String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", "Data Key is: " + dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
adapter = new SellerProductsAdapter(data, getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Snapshot of my db structure
[image]

Nevia node data:

[image]

Comment: How much data exists under `root/Product/$UID`? So please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo currently there is only single data. please have a look at the sanpshot of my db attached with the question.

Comment: And how much data exists under `nevia`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have attached image of nevia node data in the question

Comment: I am only displaying the data of "name", "image1" and "price" nodes data in the recyclerview

Comment: That's it all, 9 fields? This is everything that exists under `nevia`, and it takes 30-50 seconds to load them?

Comment: yes these are all the fields under nevia and it takes 30-50 seconds to laod

Comment: I cannot see something at a first glance that can delay the request by 30-50 seconds. But hopefully, someone will see. Or maybe, it's not about the code, but your connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `notifyDataSetChanged` needs to be inside `onDataChange`, so that it tells the adapter to refresh its views whenever the data is loaded.

```
databaseReference.child("Product").child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                HomeFragmentModel homeFragmentModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(HomeFragmentModel.class);
                data.add(homeFragmentModel);
                String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", "Data Key is: " + dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
adapter = new SellerProductsAdapter(data, getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```